# How to get a string resource in C# (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, localizable.strings

I know how to get a resource from the string resource in XAML:

```
{Binding OK, Source={StaticResource LocStrings}}
```

However, I want to use a localized string in C# directly, e.g. something like

```
someString = Resources["LocStrings"]["StringId"];
```

But this does not compile.

Comment: (Sorry I already  know the answer ... I just saw the resource code behind):

Comment: Btw, answer is simply:   using <projname>.Resources; someString = Strings.StringId;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
var myText = this.FindResource("LocStrings") as string;
```

I guess, you can change `this` to wherever your resource is located.

**UPDATE:**

Usually, this is what I use for global resources:

```
var myText = Application.Current.FindResource("resourceName") as string;
```

Comment: Exists there no better (type-safe) way? With WinForms app getting string resource was much better: Properties.Resources.ResourceName;

Comment: None that I am aware of. But you can always check the type yourself.

Comment: It is also possible to use .resx files in a WPF app to get that benefits but I wonder that XAML doesn't provide such benefits...

Comment: AppNamespace.Properties.Resources.<name of the string in Resources.resx>. A Fundamental WPF thing!

Comment: @RobinDavies I don't use RESX files with WPF, only resource dictionaries. Right now I am not sure if your suggestion would work (it has been some years since I last checked those kind of things), but the way the question was formed, I had the impression the author wanted to get the translation based on a key of type `string`.

Answer (score 4):

Resource strings are accessible as static members in the auto-generated `Resources` class, found in `<Default.app.namespace>.Properties.Resources`. `Properties` and `Resources` are both unfortunate namespace names that clash with properties or namespaces that you probably already have in scope when writing WPF code. So you may have to use the fully-qualified name. e.g.

```
MyProject.Properties.Resources.AppName
```

for the string defined in `Resources.resx` with the name "AppName".

You should prefer this method of getting string resources over calling `FindResource`, as it provides compile-time checking of resource string names.

FFS. How can this not already be given as an answer, people?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but maybe could helps in your internationalization application, see this [codeplex article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files) maybe will be useful to you.